# git merge of one branch affected/conflicted with changes from non-involved branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control

to begin with, i must say that i'm fairly new with using Git or its advanced capabilities in terms of tracking and managing changes in a project, specially in the field of Software Development where it specializes. However, i can also say that i have enough understanding on its fundamentals and basics such as `init`, `clone`, `push`, `pull`, `merge`, and resolving conflicts.

to also add, we're working on a WinForms C# Project and is being tracked by Git with the help of **Axosoft, LLC.**'s `GitKraken` Application.

so, instead of creating branch for specific modules, we instead create branch for specific developers as they solely manage the development of it individually. to summarize this:

branches `marq`, `ja`, `ranz`, `kim`, and `kiian` - are all developers working on specific modules.
branch `development` - is a branch where we merge stable codes that are all ready for testing.

however, to lessen the confusion as i am not good in writing my concerns. let's focus on branch `development`, `ja`, and `kiian`. and that i manage both branch `kiian` and branch `development` on my local pc, which basically means i regularly switch to branch `development` and pull changes from different branches.

a few days back, branch `kiian` merged his changes to branch `development`, branch `kiian` did not pull the merged changes stored in branch `development` after that because there are no prior changes that needs to be downloaded to his local repository. until today, there have been 15+19 changes in branch `kiian`'s files prior to its last merge with branch `development`.

today, branch `ja` decided to merge his changes to branch `development`. so i switched branches from branch `kiian` to branch `development` (notice that the new changes 15+19 has not yet been committed on branch `kiian`'s local repository). I was able to switch branches successfully although i think i should not have been able to (as for what i understand, i should be allowed to unless all pending changes are committed).

now the thing that happened is, when i merged branch `ja` to branch `development`, all that pending changes (15+19) that was supposedly still on branch `kiian` was staged on the merging activity of branch `ja` and `development`. this also prompted a merge conflict on 3 files modified by branch `kiian` which is yet to be committed too. those same changes (15+19) has also been stashed on branch `kiian` which i had to pop out again.

now my question is, to summarize this is, how is it that the changes on branch `kiian` that is not yet even committed, got involved in the merging of branch `development` and `ja` which it supposedly was not involved with?

those same changes were not yet ready and should not be merged but, for some reason got merged, and that branch `kiian`'s exact copy of changes got stashed.

below is a screenshot of our graph:

[image]

Comment: When you change branch, any local changes that are not committed with be kept as is in your sandbox if they are for files that are the same between the branch where you were and the branch you are switching to. So the work in your sandbox came along when you switched branch.  Your description is a bit confusing to follow, but are the conflicts you're seeing in such local changes? Essentially, changes are not actually in a particular branch until you've committed them, they're just in your sandbox.

Comment: apologies if my explanation is confusing, i totally understand that as english is not my native language. but i think i get your point. all those changes were note staged nor committed to a specific branch. as such, your explanation made sense - in that they currently do not belong to any branch and the moment i switched to the development branch, it considered those changes its own. can you perhaps change this comment to an answer? i'd like to mark this as an answer. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change branch, any local changes that are not committed with be kept as is in your sandbox if they are for files that are the same between the branch where you were and the branch you are switching to. So the work in your sandbox came along when you switched branch. I expect the conflicts you're seeing come from such local changes. Essentially, changes are not actually in a particular branch until you've committed them, they're just in your sandbox.

Comment: thank you. that's something i was not able to understand before. i'll keep that in mind and hopes to help others with the same confusing scenario too. thank you again.